# Moving UIView plane in 2D along with accelerometer and gyro data

Tags: iphone, xcode, ipad, ios5, core-motion

Question in one line is i want to apply effect like deepEnd jailbreak app.

Details:
I have a UIImageView for the background. Above that i have added Gold coin image. What i need to do is when user tilt the ipad the background should move either x or y or in both axis according to the motion. The only thing i am not gettting is when i am holding ipad in xy plane and tilting it background not have change in x axis. Please help me . If you need more details tell me

This is the code i am using to move the background image

-(void) moveBackground:(CMAcceleration) acceleration {

```
    [_background setFrame:CGRectMake(50*acceleration.y, 50*acceleration.z, _background.bounds.size.width, _background.bounds.size.height)];
}];
```

}

[image]

Comment: Other way i want to know when we keep ios device in xy plane and tilt it which data is changed in acceleration or gyro data and specifically which axis.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are interested in [gravity](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/CoreMotion/Reference/CMDeviceMotion_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009942) present in [CMDeviceMotion Class](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/CoreMotion/Reference/CMDeviceMotion_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009942) when you [start](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/CoreMotion/Reference/CMMotionManager_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/CMMotionManager/startDeviceMotionUpdates) the 
divice motion updates, you can get the gravity(which is a acceleration) with respect to device reference plane. you can get the angle of device based on the constant gravity by using [atan2()](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cmath/atan2/) function. For example following code gives you angle of gravity about Y-Axis of the device.
`CMAcceleration gravity = motionManager.deviceMotion.gravity;
 CGFloat angle = atan2(gravity.z, gravity.x);` You need to be careful about device motion though. it may not be available on all devices (EX:iPad1) in that case u need to use `motionManager.accelerometerData.acceleration` which gives raw acceleration rather than refined gravity. one you have the angle its simple matter of mathematics to see how much your background must move.